# How to remove incorrectly added apt-get repositories

Tags: apt

I'm completely new at this, trying to deploy a meteor app. I'm trying without much success at this point to add node 0.10.40 to Ubuntu 14.04. What I have managed to do is add a bunch of non existing repositories.

How do I get rid of them?
These are the repositories I would like to get rid of:

```
Err https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
  HttpError404
Err https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main i386 Packages
  HttpError404
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/v0.10.40/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/v0.10.40/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  HttpError404
```

Where did I add these repositories to? They are not in /etc/apt/sources.list.d. In that folder I do see a repository added via the command `add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js`

Comment: It would be easiest if you could remember the exact command with which you installed the invalid repositories. Otherwise just run `grep -r --include '*.list' 'deb.nodesource.com' /etc/apt` to find out in which file the lines are.

Comment: Thank you, then I just deleted those lines from the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easiest if you could remember the exact command with which you installed the invalid repositories. Otherwise just run this to find out in which file the lines are:

```
grep -r --include '*.list' 'deb.nodesource.com' /etc/apt
```

If they're the only lines in the file that do not start with an `#`, you can delete the entire file. Else just remove these specific lines. You can also just disable the lines by commenting them out. To do that, simply write an `#` in the very beginning of each line.